# @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) lost with @AttributeOverride

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, embeddable

I need to use `@AttributeOverride` on an `@Embeddable` object to prevent collision of the column names for two properties of the same complex type.

However, when doing so, I also lose/override the `@Enumerated` annotation of the `networkId` property of the `@Embedded` `ExternalLink` object.

In the end, the column `link_network` of the table is of type `integer`, instead of `varyingchar(255)`.

How can I configure the `@AttributeOverride` to keep the `@Enumerated` configuration?

Here is my schema:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="network", column=@Column(name="link_network")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="networkAddress", column=@Column(name="link_network_address")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="element", column=@Column(name="link_element"))
    })
    private ExternalLink link;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="network", column=@Column(name="before_network")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="networkAddress", column=@Column(name="before_network_address")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="element", column=@Column(name="before_element"))
    })
    private ExternalLink before;
}

@Embeddable
public class ExternalLink {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private NetworkId network;
    private String networkAddress;
    private String element;
}
```

Comment: I use your code and everything was fine, all columns are in type varchar(255)

Comment: Which database/backend do you map this schema to?

Comment: I am using `org.postgresql.Driver` @MWiesner and Hibernate 5.0.11

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know is converter, which maps `NetworkId` to `String` (varchar)

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class NetworkIdConverter implements AttributeConverter<NetworkId , String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(NetworkId attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return attribute.name();
    }

    @Override
    public NetworkId convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return NetworkId.valueOf(dbData);
    }
}
```